# Exception for a class that extends PDO?

Tags: class, pdo

I have a class that extends PDO and makes a connection like this :

```
class DBConnection extends PDO {  
 protected static $config = array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname' => 'test'
); 
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct("mysql:host=".self::$config['host'].";dbname=".self::$config['dbname'].";charset=utf8", 
            self::$config['username'], self::$config['password']);

    $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
}
```

}

How can I check for any exceptions of the parent class ? I mean if there's a problem in the config array the message is given raw to the user, but I don't want this ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the message is given raw to the user

Just tell PHP not to do so

```
display_errors = 0
```

in `php.ini` or using [whatever else method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)